# How can I check whether file is successfully uploaded & retry uploading in sometime at shell script?

Tags: shell, ftp, rhel5

I am running shell script which is upload result file to remove server.
One day, ftp server is crashed but nobody didn't know it,so daily data isn't generated on time.

To prevent this issue, my manager ask me to check the uploading result and try to upload it in some delay. ( Try each hour 2 ~ 3 times. )

I have questions.
  1. How can I detect whether file uploading is success ? 
  2. How can I re-schedule file uploading in sometimes ?

FYI, our system is running on RHEL5 and below is file uploading code.

```
ftp -n -v ${FTP_HOST} << END_SCRIPT

user ${FTP_USER} ${FTP_PASSWD}

prompt

binary

put  ${REPORT__NAME}.tar.gz

bye

END_SCRIPT
```

Comment: `md5sum` can be used to verify it. You could use `cron` to time it.

Answer (score 1):

a lazy (easy, but not very clever) solution :

- 1) compute the MD5sum of the file :  `md5sum ZEFILE > ZEFILE-MD5.txt`
- 2) upload the file : `put ZEFILE`

If you can run commands on the remote server :

- 3) just behind, a 2nd command (so it's run only after the first) : `put ZEFILE-MD5.txt`
- 4) on the remote server : it waits until a "ZEFILE" also have a "ZEFILE-MD5.txt" with it, showing the file is probably fully uploaded. IT then compare the md5sum of ZEFILE with the content of ZEFILE-MD5.txt, and warns you (mail?) that ZEFILE is "corrupted"

If you don't have access to the remote server:

- 3) try to download ZEFILE again under another name: `get ZEFILE ZEFILE-from-remote`
- 4) `diff ZEFILE ZEFILE-from-remote`

I'd also recommand, if you have (some) access to the remote server, to use "scp ZEFILE  user@destination:/some/path/" insead of using FTP.

If forced to use FTP : read about using `expect` instead of writing a static script that can't "adapt" to remotely sent error messages (nor wait for proper prompts before issuing the relevant commands)

And about the rescheduling :  `man at`

You could do :   `echo /path/to/myscript | at now + 3 hours` (check the syntax please, writing from memory of reading that man page a few years back...) (the script could re-submit itself that way, but beware of infinite loops ^^)

I hope this helps (and that someone comes up with a "cleverer" idea ^^)